# How to update records belongs to same partition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in a database containing the following data:

```
     GroupId    ExceptionId ParentExceptionId   row
       1           101           NULL            1
       1           102           NULL            2
       1           103           NULL            3
       2           104           NULL            1
       2           105           NULL            2
       2           106           NULL            3
       3           107           NULL            1
       3           108           NULL            2`
```

I worte a following query to get the above row number:

```
    with CTE_RN as
    (
     SELECT  a.[GroupId], a.[SolId], a.[id],ParentExceptionId,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.[GroupId] ORDER BY a.[GroupId]) AS [row]
     FROM [dbo].[trn_Report6_Zone1_Exception] a)
     select * from cte_rn`
```

expected output:
update `ParentExceptionId` with `ExceptionId` of first record having same group id and keep `ParentExceptionId` of that first record null.

```
     GroupId    ExceptionId ParentExceptionId   row
       1           101           NULL            1
       1           102           101             2
       1           103           101             3
       2           104           Null            1
       2           105           104             2
       2           106           104             3
       3           107           NULL            1
       3           108           107             2`
```

Comment: Having the same columns/expressions in both `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` says that *you don't actually care about any ordering*. Is that truly the case here? So it would be equally valid that `ExceptionId` 103 was assigned row number 1 within `GroupId` 1 and the others 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [first_value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function :

```
select GroupId, ExceptionId, 
       (case when f_value <> ExceptionId then f_value end) as ParentExceptionId, row
from (select *, first_value(ExceptionId) over (partition by GroupId order by ExceptionId) f_value
      from [dbo].[trn_Report6_Zone1_Exception] a
     ) a;
```

In same way you can use `updateable` cte :

```
with a as (
     select *, first_value(ExceptionId) over (partition by GroupId order by ExceptionId) f_value
     from [dbo].[trn_Report6_Zone1_Exception] a
 )

update a
     set ParentExceptionId  = f_value
where f_value <> ExceptionId;
```

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh it worked! first_value() is it a inbuilt function?

Comment: @PriyankaDesai. . . Yes but start with version 2012 +.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   SELECT * INTO #TAB FROM 
   (select 1,101,NULL,1 UNION ALL
   select 1,102,NULL,2 UNION ALL
   select 1,103,NULL,3 UNION ALL
   select 2,104,NULL,1 UNION ALL
   select 2,105,NULL,2 UNION ALL
   select 2,106,NULL,3 UNION ALL
   select 3,107,NULL,1 UNION ALL
   select 3,108,NULL,2  
   )AS TABLEA(GroupId,ExceptionId,ParentExceptionId,rowW)

;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT GroupId, MIN(ExceptionId) MIN_ExceptionId
FROM #TAB
GROUP BY GroupId
)
UPDATE T SET T.ParentExceptionId = C.MIN_ExceptionId
FROM #TAB T
INNER JOIN CTE C ON T.GroupId = C.GroupId
WHERE rowW <>1
```

Comment: Which is this rowW column?

Comment: your row column.. Typo here @PriyankaDesai